# What is Knockout custom binding "after" variable?

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I am using *knockout* with *ASP.NET MVC* for some project. 
I am using the following `bindingHandler` of knockout

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    after: ["options", "value", "selectedOptions"],
    init: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        // no explicit reference to the 'after' variable
    },
    update: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        // no explicit reference to the 'after' variable
    }
}
```

I got this code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38013879/4390133) and I modified it little. 
 It is basically a `custom binding handler` for the [Select2 plugin](https://select2.github.io/).

**Question** 
I just want to know what the `after: ["options", "value", "selectedOptions"],` means here. There is no reference to this variable anywhere in the `init` or `update` functions. 
Does this variable have any meaning in this context? or is this an instruction to knockout to make it execute this custom binding after finish executing [`options`, `value`, `selectedOptions`] bindings?

**Note**
the documentation of the [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) mentions nothing about this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in that it appears to be undocumented. Digging into the [KO source code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/bindingAttributeSyntax.js#L258) shows us this:

```
// First add dependencies (if any) of the current binding
if (binding['after']) {
    cyclicDependencyStack.push(bindingKey);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(binding['after'], function(bindingDependencyKey) {
        if (bindings[bindingDependencyKey]) {
            if (ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(cyclicDependencyStack, bindingDependencyKey) !== -1) {
                throw Error("Cannot combine the following bindings, because they have a cyclic dependency: " + cyclicDependencyStack.join(", "));
            } else {
                pushBinding(bindingDependencyKey);
            }
        }
    });
    cyclicDependencyStack.length--;
}
```

Your assumption appears to be correct. KO is building a list of dependent bindings that must run before the current binding can run. The built-in [value](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/61c039f0de9a7142a76f153f6fcc2f6c1b5e6df1/src/binding/defaultBindings/value.js) and [selectedOptions](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/241c26ca82e6e4b3eaee39e3dc0a92f85bc1df0c/src/binding/defaultBindings/selectedOptions.js) bindings take advantage of this keyword.

Here is the [discussion on implementation from the Knockout Github](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/950)

Here is a related [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25649440/6913494)

See the JSFiddle in that answer for example code.